# MySQL on Linux (Redhat) freezing with queries on large tables

Tags: linux, mysql, database, lamp

We have a server running LAMP which contains a number of zencart sites. We noticed a problem when trying to view orders in one of the sites and it timed-out. Now when I do:

```
"select * from orders"
```

The whole thing freezes, so does:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Now the orders table should have around 42000 orders in it, do it's not THAT large. Can anyone reccommend any good diagnostic techniques to figure out whats going wrong?

Comment: by freezes I mean...it does what it would normally do when processing a query that would take some time. But doesn't actually do anything. It's been in "Query is being executed..." for approx 45 minutes. The server setup (ie cpu, ram etc) its more than capable to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you do "explain select * from orders" query? and "select count(*) from orders" ?
Explain statement should give you some insight in whats happening with your query (it explains how server will execute it and helps you to diagnose a bottleneck) and count(*) will let you know, if 42 000 you mentioned is still in that range.

Answer (score 1):

I thnk there is  a problem with your index.
Can you try

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `orders`
CHECK TABLE `orders`
REPAIR TABLE `orders`
```

Also you can try dumping and recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this. Using MySQL Query browser it allowed me to see the current running threads. There were a few intensive MyIsam quaries that were locking the table for some reason. I killed these and the backlog cleared in seconds. Back to normal. Woop!